# How to decode cbor encoded hex string using perl libraries?

Tags: perl, decoding, cbor

I have a cbor encoded hex string.

when decoding using CBOR::XS

But I am getting an error as
garbage after CBOR object, at offset 2 (octet 0x41) at new.pl line 6.

```
use CBOR::XS;
# Replace this with your CBOR-encoded hex data
my $hex_data = "";

# Decode CBOR data
my $decoded_data = CBOR::XS::decode_cbor($hex_data);
# Manually format the decoded data
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper($decoded_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub does not want the hex representation of the bytes but the bytes themselves.

```perl
my $data = pack "H*", $hex_data;
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256119/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-how-to-decode-cbor-encoded-hex-string-using-perl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.